# How to reorder tableview cells by date from the last .POST

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, date, swift4

I'm currently doing a .GET in a tableview to display notes. It's working like a charm. Anyway, what I want now is to order the notes by last date.

I know that there is the 'reduce' function, I did this on my date array but it's not working.

> .reduce(Date.distantPast, { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 })

Comment: User `sort`, not `reduce`

Comment: use the .sort instead of reduce

Comment: why you are using reduce it should be sort  , You have date object or String object in your array ?

Comment: use `.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})`

Comment: The comments suggesting `.sort` are correct. However, if you control the API you are getting the data from, the sorting should really be handled by the backend. Databases can do filtering and sorting much more efficiently than your client devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
let datesArray = ["01 Feb, 2017","01 Jan, 2017", "10 Feb, 2017"]
var convertedArray: [Date] = []

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM, yyyy"

for dat in datesArray {
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)
    if let date = date {
        convertedArray.append(date)
    }
}

let sortedArray = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending })
print(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks every one for your answers. It was very useful. I fixed my problem by doing this.

```
self._noteList.sort(by: { $0.createDate.compare($1.createDate) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
```